# Google font does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

Can someone please help me get a grasp of what's going on with [this site](http://ecosafe.screenpartner.no/om-ecosafe/) in Internet Explorer? I tested the site in every other browser (Safari, Opera, Chrome, Firefox), but I don't have any means of testing in IE.

I put the site on a live testserver for the client to check out, and they're sending me screenshots of broken layouts and missing text sections.

It seems the issue is related to the Google font I'm using. Exchanging the font with Helvetica renders expected results, but whenever the font is active only parts of the websites text renders.

All I've done to use this font is copy paste the Google font:

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

And I'm using this as my css rule:

`font-family: "Titillium Web", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`

**EDIT**

I managed to finally fix the issue by downloading the "Titillium Web" from Google and converting it to a webfont with fontsquirrel.

IE is still having some issues rendering characters like `æøå`.

Comment: Check out Browserstack (https://www.browserstack.com) to test all browses, and Microsoft even offers free downloads of virtual machines to test IE with (https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/). Also, what version of IE is your client using? When I test it in IE9 is it working fine. It crashed on IE8.

Comment: I think the client uses IE 10 or 11. I've had a trial at browserstack, but it's expired and I can't afford it atm.

Comment: Your font is loading correctly in IE10 and IE11 and it all looks fine in my browserstack. Make sure to ask your client for screenshots and documentation on what they are seeing. It is possible that your site is falling back on quirks mode, so be sure to use the meta tag to force modern behaviour: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. Otherwise it might be best to download one of those VMs and test in there.

Comment: I'm already using that meta tag. Let me include some screenshots I got from the client. The problem is not that the font is not loading, it's that some paragraphs (seemingly random) doesn't render. `<p>rendered</p>` `<p>not rendered</p>` `<p>rendered</p>`, etc..

Comment: From your comment it kind of looks like your paragraph tags are inverted... Is that so?

Comment: Wouldn't that be weird if they still display in every other browser..? Just to be sure I checked and they're not :/

Comment: I’m not seeing the issue at all. Definitely ask your client for their OS version and browser version as well as any browser add-ons they might have installed. Then set up a virtual machine with the same config. That should help you diagnose the issue if it is still happening.

Comment: @AaronGustafson , the issue was there (the site link was sent around the client board :S), but I managed to eventually fix it by downloading the Google font and converting it to a webfont with fontsquirrel. It's not completely fixed as some æøå characters are rendering weird, but luckily the text is displaying.